# Diagram evaluation with 3 possible results

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, diagram

[image]

Is there a way to check the color of this diagram without using too much if?

Not like this:

```
if(x == "b" && y == "b"){ return "red";}
if(x == "b" && y == "e1" || x == "b" && y == "e2" .....){ return "green";}
........
```

I think there must be a way to simple calculate the result with given values for the characters, but I can't find it.

Something like checking `x+y=z` or `x*y=z`. Where z can be one of three numbers.

The language doesn't matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend targeting the red diagonal and green column, picking off individual cases and then returning yellow:

```
if x == "i"{ return "yellow"}
if y == "i"{ return "yellow"}
if x[0] == y[0]{ return "green"}
/*
target remaining green cases
*/
return "yellow"
```

Comment: Thanks, I now did this: I put all values in a database and check every time I get two characters for the element in the db. But thank you very much!